# Deleting an individual row in Arc Map based on a value with Python

Tags: python, row, arcmap

I am having difficulty deleting just a single row in a shapefile attribute table with Python script. What I would like to do is delete any row that has ID value = 0. Whith the scripts I've been using all rows get deleted. I have tried numerous scripts, for example (note that "final" in this case is my shapefile).

```
fieldsNew = arcpy.ListFields(final)

listID = []
for field in fieldsNew:
        header = ("{0}".format(field.name))
        string = str(header)
        if string.startswith('ID'):
            listID .append(string)

for j in listID:
        curObjX = arcpy.UpdateCursor(final)
        for rowX in curObjX:
            rowValue = rowX.getValue(j)    
            if rowValue != 0:
                pass

            else:
                print rowX
                curObjX.deleteRow(rowX)
```

or

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(final)
fields = arcpy.ListFields(final)



for row in rows:
    for field in fields:
        if field.name == 'ID':
            value = row.getValue(field.name)
            if value == 0:
                print row
                rows.deleteRow(row)
            else:
                pass
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you run the script inside of ArcMap in the python window, you could do the following:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("final","NEW_SELECTION",'"Id" = 0')
>>> arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("final")
```

If you run your script outside of the ArcMap environment, then you would just need to set the working directory and point the script to the "final.shp" before doing the selections.

Hopefully this helps